# how to send parameters to databricks notebook?

Tags: python, databricks

I triggering databricks notebook using the following code:

```
TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % TOKEN}
data = {
    "job_id": xx,
    "notebook_task": {
        "base_parameters": {
            "param1":"key1",
            "param2": "key2",
        }
    },
}

resp = requests.post(
    "https://xxxxxx.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/jobs/run-now",
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(data),
)
```

when i try to access it using `dbutils.widgets.get("param1")`, im getting the following error:

```
com.databricks.dbutils_v1.InputWidgetNotDefined: No input widget named param1
```

I tried using notebook_params also, resulting in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`base_parameters` is used only when you create a job.  When you trigger it with `run-now`, you need to specify parameters as `notebook_params` object ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunNow)), so your code should be :

```py
data = {
    "job_id": xx,
    "notebook_params": {
        "param1":"key1",
        "param2": "key2",
    },
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing as above. Using dbutils.widgets.get("param1") is giving the following error: com.databricks.dbutils_v1.InputWidgetNotDefined: No input widget named param1 is defined

Comment: I believe you must also have the cell command to create the widget inside of the notebook.  Normally that command would be at or near the top of the notebook